# Imagen en page-php

Tags: php, template

Buenas,

Tengo un problema con dos imagenes que tengo en un archivo llamado page-equipo.php. El código que tengo de php es este:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ): while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<section class="cuadricula_clinicas">
  <p class="clinica_oropesa"><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'medium' );   ?></p>
    <p class="clinica_valencia"><?php the_post_thumbnail( 'medium' );   ?></p>
</section>
```

Y el código de CSS donde cargaba la imagen:

```
.clinica_oropesa {
  width: 50%;
  height: 75%;

  margin-right: 1rem;

/*  background: url('imagenes/jpg/clinica_oropesa.jpg') no-repeat;*/
  background-size: cover;
```

En la pagina de Wordpress le añado esto:

```
<img src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/clinica_oropesa-1024x768.jpg" alt="" width="1024" height="768" class="alignleft size-large wp-image-85" />
```

Lo que hago es comentar en el CSS la imagen y la llamo a través del template tag the_post_thumnail(), pero no aparece nada.

¿Me falta algo? ¿Tengo algún error en el código?

Gracias!!!

Comment: ¿Quieres que los posts tengan dos `thumbnail`?

Comment: Si, eso es.  Es posible?

Comment: Nada es imposible. Aunque no le veo mucho sentido a tener dos thumbnail. [Esto te puede interesar](http://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-add-multiple-post-thumbnails-featured-images-in-wordpress/)